# Reverse engineering key fob RF signals

Tags: rf, signal-processing, demodulation, sdr

I have been trying to decode the signal of a keyfob with a cheap `315MHz` RF receiver (`XY-MK-5V`) and a `ESP32 WROOM` module. The signal was sampled at 105060 samples per second. I would like to understand from first principles what is happening and why I'm not getting a clear signal (I could buy an SDR but prefer to try to start understanding from scratch).

It gets the first preamble quite nicely. Note it starts `1000...` so it can't be Manchester encoding. Each peak is ~54 samples wide so it's a signal of around `2kHz`.
[image]

Some samples later however, the head of the first package gets jumbled. Each peak on the jumbled head is ~10 samples wide, so it's a signal of around `10kHz`. Way higher than the preamble.
[image]

The same pattern repeats for every next package: head is jumbled, tail is clear.
[image]

The very last package is quite strange, because it has a jumbled head, then a steady high signal, then a high frequency period, then an even higher frequency period, and then a jumbled tail.

[image]

What can this mean?

- Maybe sampling at considerably more than 105060 samples per second is necessary? (not possible with my current components)
- Maybe it's not purely ASK modulation?
- Maybe my `XY-MK-5V` receiver or the the ADC of my `ESP32 WROOM` are too cheap?

I'm thinking about buying an SDR but would like to understand the basics and principles of it before buying such an out of the box component.

Any help furthering my understanding is very welcome.

Comment: I wouldn’t suggest using the adc for ASK it is a digital signal. I’d use a cheapy Salae logic clone logic analyser to capture the data. It could also be your receiver is garbage. At a pinch, use your sound card line input and there’s free utilities that will sample the data. This would rule out any weirdness on the esp32 side.

Comment: As well, when the fob is not transmitting, you’ll get random garbage as you observe. The preamble allows the receiver to set its slice level to digitize the output.

Comment: Do you have access to a spectrum analyser? You'll probably be able to tell a lot of which modulation that's used by looking at the carrier alone. FSK, ASK, OOK and so on look quite different - you might even be able to tell which kind of FSK modulation it uses if FSK.